# Excel only add to drop down list if adjacent column equals "YES"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a problem, that seem like a bigger problem to solve than I first thought!

I got this setup:

[image]

I am using `Data Validation` to fetch the items for the **Choose Teacher** drop down. So far so good!

What I need is somehow to *only* add the teachers with `Yes` in the adjacent **Active** cell. I tried to add this formula to the data validation source `=IF($B$2:$B$5,"Yes";$A$2:$A$5)` does not work, not sure how to implement this formula to a range, or if this even is the way to go to solve this issue!

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that requires a helper; not sure if that's acceptable:
If you set a FILTER in C1: `=FILTER(A:A,B:B="yes")`

Then you can store a named range referring to this range as: `=C1:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))`

You can then use the named range in your list.

(Cannot test it myself, since Excel for mobile does not allow naming ranges or listing.)

Edit: Harun24H mentioned a much simpler solution. Avoiding named ranges you can refer to the spill range directly in you list source like in example below:
[image]

Comment: If OP has filter formula then no need named range. May use `=C1#` in data validation list.

Comment: You can not refer to a spill range in named ranges, unfortunately.

Comment: Not in named range but you can refer spilled range in data validation list.

Comment: That would indeed make it way more easy

Comment: Best not tell my spreadsheet - it's got about 20 spilled named ranges and hasn't realised.  I then use the named ranges in charts so it all updates nicely.

Comment: Edited the answer to show Harun24H's suggestion works